# cambiar el color de un div de una pagina externa desde un complemento

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

hice un complemento para chrome, la funcionalidad es cambiar el color del div "textarea_simulator" de la pagina ..., solo por hacer la prueba estoy jugando con ese div pero no puedo cambiar el color, este es mi codigo js.

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.getElementById(textarea_simulator).style.backgroundColor="red"'
  });
});
```

y el archivo manifest.json es:

```
{
  "name": "cambio del color",
  "description": "cambio de color",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "cambiar la vista en chrome "
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

hice la prueba para cambiar el color del fondo hice la prueba con google, con esta version de mi codigo y funciona.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue"'
  });
});
```

Comment: ¿Por qué como background y no como content_scripts? ¿La idea es camiarlo siempre / sólo cuando se hace click en el icono en la barra en Chrome?

Comment: @Mariano siempre seria ideal, solo conozco background, como seria con content_script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma en que lo estás implementando es para cuando se hace click en el icono de la extensión, cargando un script que se ejecuta en segundo plano y cuando estás en un tab que coincide con la URL... **un poco complicado por demás** :-)

Para inyectar código JavaScript o CSS en una página, conviene usar [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Esta sería la configuración *básica* del **manifest.json**:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "cambio del color",
    "description": "cambio de color",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "m3w",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon16.png",
        "48": "images/icon48.png",
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "*://www.ruat.gob.bo/Principal.jsf"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://www.ruat.gob.bo/Principal.jsf"
            ],
            "js": ["cambiarcolor.js"],
            "css": ["cambiarcolor.css"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

Observá el final: estamos inyectando un archivo con código JavaScript que se ejecutará en [`document_end`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at) (cuando se termina de cargar el DOM), y un CSS (sólo porque lo voy a usar en el 2do ejemplo, pero podés borrarlo).

**cambiarcolor.js**

```js
var simulator = document.getElementById('textarea_simulator');
if (simulator) {
    simulator.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

console.debug('Se cargó la extensión: Cambiar Color');
```

¿Más sencillo, no?

---

Otra alternativa sería sin usar JavaScript, directamente usando el CSS que definimos en el manifest.

**cambiarcolor.css**

```css
#textarea_simulator {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: si se ve mucho mas sencillo y entendible, pero no logro hacer funcionar, el mensaje "Se cargó la extensión: Cambiar Color" no muestra por consola

Comment: Acabo de cargarlo como extensión y funcionó. Asegurate de: recargar la extensión en `chrome://extensions/`, ver que no haya errores (los mostraría como que no pudo cargarla debajo del nombre de tu extensión) y estar abriendo la página `www.ruat.gob.bo/Principal.jsf` (que es la única en la que tiene permisos).

Comment: ya funciona, pero no cambia de color, y el tuyo?